# String not passing properly through shell_exec to a bash script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

Input text in page1:

```
...
<form name="myform" action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" size="92" name="my_text" />
...
```

page2.php:

```
...
$our_text = ($_POST['my_text']);
```

Until now we're ok, and `echo $our_text` still gives me the right string.
but then, when passing `$subject` to a bash script:

```
...
shell_exec("./myscript.sh '$our_text'");
```

in myscript.sh:

```
...
still_our_text=$1
echo $still_our_text > log.txt
```

in `log.txt`, I have my complete string if it has only standard letters and spaces. But if there is an apostrophe
or a letter with an accent (French é or è or ê), then I only get strange things
"I will do it now" is kept intact in `log.txt`
"I'll do it now" just doesn't work, `log.txt` is not created
"L'éléphant va bien" (which means the elephant feels well...), actually puts "LÃ©lÃ©phant" in log.txt, and if we pass additional arguments through shell exec, the other words are passed in the other arguments
For example If I pass 4 arguments to shell exec:

```
1: "L'éléphant va bien"
2: "go"
3: 4
4: "stop"
```

Then in `scrip.sh`, if I echo `$1` to `$4` in `log.txt`, I have:

```
1: LÃ©lÃ©phant
2: va
3: bien
4:
```

But sometimes it just doesn't work and nothing get written in `log.txt`.

Any idea on how to fix this and correctly pass a string through shell_exec, so I recover my full string in the bash script ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) should work. Take the following example:

#### ourtext.php

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
$our_text = "L'éléphant va bien";
shell_exec('./myscript.sh ' . escapeshellarg($our_text));
```

#### myscript.sh

```
still_our_text=$1
printf '%s\n' "$still_our_text" >log.txt
```

(Made a few changes to be make it more robust)

Then run it like so from the command line:

```
$ php ourtext.php; cat log.txt
L'éléphant va bien
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried to incorporate this in my files (html form => php => script), and there is a difference, now it does go to log.txt with the apostrophe, but the "é" are removed !

Comment: This happens in php file when escapeshellarg is used. In php if I echo $out_text before and after escapeshellarg, I have first L'éléphant va bien and then 'L'\''lphant va bien'   !

Comment: @Alex Have you tried explicitly setting the locale? I updated the example.

Comment: Yes, LC_LCTYPE was the issue, and also the dos2unix command to solve the return line issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) ?

Comment: Nope, same behaviour. I added "$our_text= escapeshellarg($our_text);" before calling shell_exec, but doesn't help.